# Resize divs on page load and window resize

Tags: jquery

Ok so I'm trying to get the height from the id `sna` and add it to three DIVs with the class `.sn_cat` on both page **load** and on window **resize**. This script adds very strange values or simply doesn't work at all. I'd like to see only suggestions that use jQuery. This height will be used on parts that the CSS can't reach (no parent and child relation).

```
$(function (){
    /* Resize right Sticky notes Height */
    function resizeColumnHeigh() {  

            var snaHeight = $("#sna").height();

            $(this).find(".sn_cat").height(snaHeight);


    }   
    /* On window resize adjust the height */
    $(window).resize(function(){
         resizeColumnHeigh();
    });

    /* Run function */
    resizeColumnHeigh();        

});
```

A fiddle to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/v4HJ5/

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense to me .... what are you trying to change the height of ? and what should the value be ? are you trying to get the `div`s with the `class` `sn_cat` to all have equal height ?

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4HJ5/3/)*

Simple, you need to reset the classes height before getting the new `#sna` height! take a look:

```
function resizeColumns() {
    $('.sn_cat').css({height:'auto'}).height( $('#sna').height() );
}
resizeColumns();

$(window).resize(function(){
     resizeColumns();
});
```

if you use images inside your `.sn_cat` you better also call your `resizeColumns()` function on `$(window).load`